# Sql query null value insertion

Tags: sql, join, null

Sql Query

```
SELECT      respondant.respondant_firstname     as first_name,
            question.question_id                as question_id,                                        
            answer.answer_id,
            answer.answer_text,
            answer.answer_rate,
            answer.answer_nps,
            question_radio.question_radio_text  as opt 
FROM        question 
LEFT JOIN   answer          on  answer.answer_question_id = question.question_id 
LEFT JOIN   question_radio  on  answer.answer_question_radio_id = question_radio.question_radio_id
LEFT JOIN   respondant      on  answer.answer_respondant_id = respondant.respondant_id 
WHERE       question.question_feedback_id = 1                                         
ORDER BY    question.question_id, answer.answer_id
```

Output:

```
first_name question_id answer_id answer_text answer_rate answer_nps  opt
RM            1          1                     5         NULL       NULL
Y             1          3                     0         NULL       NULL
Ben           1          5                     0         NULL       NULL
akash         1          8                    2.5        NULL       NULL
RM            2          2                     0           4        NULL
Y             2          4                     0           3        NULL
Ben           2          6                     0           0        NULL
akash         2          9                     0           0        NULL
Ben           3          7         Thanks      0           0        NULL
akash         3          10                    0           0        NULL
```

I Need the output as:

```
first_name question_id answer_id answer_text answer_rate answer_nps  opt
RM            1          1                     5         NULL       NULL
Y             1          3                     0         NULL       NULL
Ben           1          5                     0         NULL       NULL
akash         1          8                    2.5        NULL       NULL
RM            2          2                     0           4        NULL
Y             2          4                     0           3        NULL
Ben           2          6                     0           0        NULL
akash         2          9                     0           0        NULL
RM            3          NULL                  0           0        NULL
Y             3          NULL                  0           0        NULL
Ben           3          NULL        ThankS    0           0        NULL
akash         3          NULL                  0           0        NULL
```

Where in third and fourth row from last doesnt have the id 3 but i need to replace as 3 and other values in that two rows has to be null

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.  Also, why are you losing the `answer_id` information in those rows?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is rather complicated.  You want a row for each responder and question, and then to fill in the details for those that responded.  My guess is that you want the `answer_id` filled in, where available.  That is, your desired results should have `answer_id`s for "Ben" and "Akash".

The following query generates all the rows using a `cross join` between the responders and the questions.  Then it brings in the additional information:

```
SELECT r.respondant_firstname as first_name, q.question_id as question_id,                                        
       a.answer_id, a.answer_text, a.answer_rate, a.answer_nps,
       qr.question_radio_text  as opt 
FROM respondant r CROSS JOIN
     question q LEFT JOIN
     answer a
     on a.answer_question_id = q.question_id and
        a.answer_respondant_id = r.respondant_id LEFT JOIN
     question_radio  qr
     on a.answer_question_radio_id = qr.question_radio_id              
WHERE q.question_feedback_id = 1                                         
ORDER BY q.question_id, a.answer_id;
```

Comment: Thanks For the help man
i need rows for each responder and question which is that

Comment: i need rows for each responder and question 
which must be like:
rm     1
y       1
ben   1
aksh  1
rm      2
y        2
ben    2
aksh    2
rm      3
y      3
ben   3
akash 3     should be in this order

Comment: That is what `respondant r CROSS JOIN question q` does: it gives every combination of people and questions.  Then,  the `ORDER BY q.question_id` takes care of giving all the `1` questions, followed by all the `2` questions, etc.

Comment: Cross join din't helped me